# Element conjugate to a maximal torus

Tags: gr.group-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras

It is well known that  any element in a compact connected Lie group is conjugate to an element in a maximal torus. Let G be a Lie group that is not necessarily compact and/or connected. Let $x\in G$ be an element of finite order, i.e. $x^n=e$ for some positive integer $n$. Is $x$ conjugate to an element in a maximal torus of G? Alternatively, let K be a maximal compact subgroup of G. Is $x$ conjugate to an element of K?

Comment: For the last question (is every element of finite order conjugate to an element in a maximal compact subgroup): yes, every compact subgroup in a virtually connected Lie group is contained in a maximal compact subgroup. This applies to finite subgroups. (Of course I need to assume virtually connected. Otherwise, every discrete group is a 0-dimensional Lie group and this yields many counterexamples.)

Comment: As regards the question about maximal tori, it would be better to first define what you mean by a maximal torus in an arbitrary (virtually connected) Lie group. Have in mind that the definition of "torus" is variable.

Comment: As a reference for YCor's comment on the last question: Hilgert and Neeb, Structure and Geometry of Lie Groups, Theorem 14.1.3 (Maximal Compact Subgroups)

Comment: I guess that a torus has to be connected, so if $G=\pm 1$, $-1$ is not conjugate to an element in a torus.

Comment: Even if one makes the expansive definition that is sometimes used that a 'torus' in a disconnected, reductive, linear Lie group is the centraliser of an honest torus (maximal Zariski-connected subgroup consisting of semisimple elements), then @BenMcKay's [counterexample](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/418670/element-conjugate-to-a-maximal-torus#comment1074856_418670) can be souped up:  consider for $G$ the normaliser of the diagonal torus inside $\operatorname{SL}_2(\mathbb C)$, and for $x$ the element $\begin{pmatrix} & 1 \\ -1 \end{pmatrix}$.